# How to use IN clause in JPA query in Java?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have this code below:

```
public Optional<KoKur> getExchangeRateFromList(final Integer code, List<KotukOdeme> paymentList){

    List<LocalDate> paymentDateList = null;
    for(KotukOdeme kotukOdeme : paymentList){
        paymentDateList.add(kotukOdeme.getOdemeTarihi());
    }

    CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<KoKur> query = cb.createQuery(KoKur.class);
    Root<KoKur> koKurRoot = query.from(KoKur.class);
    query.where(
            cb.and(
                    cb.equal(koKurRoot.get("dovizTip"), code)

            )

    );
    TypedQuery<KoKur> typedQuery = entityManager.createQuery(query);
    List<KoKur> koKurList = typedQuery.getResultList();

    return koKurList.isEmpty() ? Optional.empty() : Optional.of(koKurList.get(0));
}
```

I am collecting list of localdates in paymentDateList, I want to add these as IN clause in my query. So beside "code", also i want to add IN next to my AND clause. When I add like below IDE gives me error;

```
cb.in(koKurRoot.get("tarih"), paymentDateList)
```

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `cb.in(koKurRoot.get("tarih")).value(paymentDateList)`

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Add other conditions to predicates array if you need

```
List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();    
predicates.add(query.get("tarih").in(paymentDateList))

query.where(cb.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()])));
return entityManager.createQuery(query).getResultList();
```

Comment: this worked also, i couldnt select as useful bcz of my reputation